# Strange Pattern: all functions/methods return error-code using the same type in C++

Tags: c++, c, coding-style

In my last two projects I've seen the strange guideline, "All Methods/Functions should return error-code using some common ERROR_CODE type". In both projects ERROR_CODE is an int typedef.

Is there any good reason doing it in C++? Some MISRA requirement or something like that?

I can see only disadvantages:

- If a function should return a value, it is done by argument reference. e.g.:

  string s;
  ERROR_CODE err = getString(s);
- The importance of a function is not obvious. All looks the same. The list of errors conntains hundreds of errors from low level errors to some domain specific errors.

Have you experienced this programming style? Are there good arguments against it or for it?

Comment: Take a look at (Windows) NT. All system calls, and most other functions return NTSTATUS values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a very bad style for several reasons.

1. Like you've said, it forces you to pass pointers/references to store the actual result of a function.
2. Like you've said, the unified error code is ugly because it's trying to unify all sorts of errors from all sorts of domains.
3. It creates an artificial dependency of all the program's modules on the error code system, making it awkward to reuse a single module or small subset of modules in other programs.
4. Further, since some of the error codes are domain-specific, it's actually introducing dependencies between unrelated object types/modules, since they're all dependent upon a component that's dependent upon the union of all of their possible error types.

My view is that any function/method which has more than a small manageable number of ways it can fail is either overly complex or poorly factored, probably both.

If you really want to return error codes, I would swap things around and pass the pointer to the error code as an argument to the function, and make the actual result the return value. Then I would choose one of these two approaches for implementing the error codes:

1. The simple way: throw away all abstraction of the error code and simply use `int` with a few universal error classes.
2. The heavy object oriented way: Provide a pointer to an internal "error object"  where the base class is very abstract and can be shared between all components without introducing any dependency, and where each component defines its own component-specific error objects if needed.

A better approach if you're using C++ would probably be using exceptions...

Comment: Good points, thank you! In both projects exceptions shouldn't be used. :-( I guess it is also a reason for unified error code rule - there is never an invalid value to return, which you usually signal by an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it.

kernel programming is that way, except when only one error is possible.

It doesn't sound like a great idea, but neither all that bad of one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not unusual for teams to agree on a common means of returning errors, since this helps in creating a common 'look and feel' to the project's code, just like any other team-wide coding convention.  This could help new team members to understand the overall picture quicker, and make maintenance within the team of other peoples' code a little more intuitive.

It's surprising to me that a C++ project is unifying behind errors rather than exceptions, however.  There's a discussion of the pros and cons of using exceptions vs error codes [here](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/exceptions-vs-status.html).

I guess one argument in favour of error code handling is if you are using a C-style API that leads you into this approach (cough... Win32... cough).

Answer (score 1):

This idiom is quite common, especially in the C world.

Even though I don't use it myself and I think it makes more harm than good (more on that in the other answers), I do find an advantage of it: a consistent way to report unexpected errors to the call site. Something like the errno variable, but easier to use.

For instance, consider a set of functions:

```
int a();
std::string b();
double c();
std::list<long> d();
```

Each of the above functions would indicate the failure in a different way: a() could return an -1, b() an empty string, c() a 0.0 and d() an empty list. That's inconsistent and not quite intuitive. Now imagine a function, whose range covers the entire possible range of the type it returns. That's even worse.

Some APIs also do:

```
int x(bool* ok);
```

But that also pollutes each function with an additional argument.

In C, there aren't many possibilities to do in a nice way, unfortunately, if you really need to design such an API that would indicate the different types of failure. In the C++ world, however, you can just use exceptions.

Comment: I think this approach is not best suitable for C++, where you can work with some kind of variant classes and return an invalid value (e.g by providing bool isValid()const; method in variant class) Indicating failure by one "magic" value of a type is ihmo very poor style.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the argument that when linking to a C++ library compiled by another compiler than is used to compile your binaries, exceptions might not work. While this non-working may totally be true, in actuality, even the linking process need not work (although everyone may be sticking to the standards), so, theoretically, this argument is void. In practice however, it *may* be (I don't have experience here, sorry), that name mangling conflicts rarely arise, alignment conflicts rarely arise, and, well, all other implementation specific stuff is widely agreed upon, except for exceptions.

Second argument I've seen is run-time performance. While stack unwinding in case of an exception *is* expensive, I've not yet seen a fair benchmark that compared exceptions to a realistic amount of return code checking.

In my typical C++ I use a mix. I use the slower exceptions for stuff that I really don't expect to happen frequently or code paths that are measured to be rarely executed, but return codes for stuff that is more likely to break and probably called frequently.
Throwing exceptions in a tight loop because some funny condition holds true in every iteration is not cheap (assuming the loop body handles it).

Comment: On Windows, COM guaranteed name mangling and alignment, so then only exceptions are likely to differ.